# How to speed up for loop

Tags: android, for-loop, textview

I dynamically add textviews to a relative layout based on user response to create a coloured grid pattern. Typically this can contain 5000+ textviews which have different background colors based on the value in textview tag.

I have this method where I iterate through all the textviews to show only those that have the same color and set the rest to gray. This works well when there are say 500 textviews but when the number is higher, say 5000 it take 13 seconds to complete.

```
if (code.equals("all")) {
    for (int i = 0; i < textViewIDs.size(); i++) {
        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(textViewIDs.get(i));
        if (!tv.getTag().toString().equals("header")) {
            tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#" + tv.getTag().toString()));
        }
    }
} else {
    for (int i = 0; i < textViewIDs.size(); i++) {
        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(textViewIDs.get(i));
        if (!tv.getTag().equals(code)) {
            if (!tv.getTag().toString().equals("header")) {
                tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
             }
        }else{
            tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#" + tv.getTag().toString()));
        }
    }
}
```

textViewIDs is the array holding all the textview ids.

What if anything can be done to speed this up?

Update:
I understand that having that number of widgets is not ideal however I could not come up with a better solution.
As well as each grid cells, in this case each texview, having different colors I also need to be able to manage onclick event for the cell so that I can add text. That was the reasoning for the textviews. Prior to using textviews I drew all the elements but that's when I couldn't find a way to add onclick event to each cell.

I'd better detail the concept to help you guys with what I'm trying to achieve and if I've gone down the wrong road.

This is part of a much larger app where I'm converting images into stitch charts. 
Based on user input a grid of colored cells is drawn where each cell is a solid color that has been calculated from the original image most dominant color. 
The grid will be larger than the screen so my views are placed in both horizontal and scroll views so they can be panned and zoomed. (This is all working well).
The grid cells have to click-able so I can turn on or off the background colors and also add a single text "X" character to mark stitch (cell) as completed.(This is to slow when the number of textview (cells) are > 500)

Hope there is enough detail there...

Comment: arrays have not get method.

Comment: well its not array, its array list... but I dont think you can actually speed up for loop ... but arrays are faster if sorted, but that want help you much :)

Comment: or maybe try to use ListView

Comment: You shouldn't have 5,000 textviews on screen at once. Perhaps you can expand on what you're trying to accomplish - perhaps a ListView or other alternative containers can provide a cleaner solution.

Comment: Can someone explain why my question has been marked down?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`findViewById()` seems to be your pressure point. 
Instead of keeping a list of the ids, I'd a keep a list of references to the `View`s themselves (`WeakReference`s if leaks are a possibility)!

Comment: Thanks, what sort of list would that be? ArrayList?

Comment: An ArrayList would definitely do the job!

Comment: After updating code with your idea (nyx), instead of 13 seconds it's now instant. Who thought that would make such a difference. I also incorporated Artoo pre calculate loop limit ideas. Thanks guys

Answer (score 1):

1 - for (int i = 0; i < textViewIDs.size(); i++) { ...
It's not optimized: **precalculate your limit** in a variable before starting the cycle:
**int len = textViewIDs.size();** and use len in your cycle.

2 - **i--** (I call it "reverse loop") seems to be faster than i++. See a nice loop comparison [here](http://www.androidsnippets.com/how-to-write-faster-loops)

Comment: That makes sense, it reduced it by 2 seconds to 11.

Comment: More items, more speed increase, of course. It's for large numbers.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bad practice to have that many `TextView`'s, low-end devices will not be able to load it.

Try making one `TextView` with multiple styles in it, you can use HTML tags for background colors.

Or even better is to create just one `ListView`, this will recycle the views for you.